# Display associative arrays 'name' in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I know my title sounds a little bit obscure, but I don't know how to describe it.

 So basically what I mean with the name of the array is, for example in this array:

```
array (size=3)
  'arrayname0' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 29
      1 => int 35
      2 => int 39
  'arrayname1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 29
      1 => int 35
      2 => int 39
  'arrayname2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 29
      1 => int 35
      2 => int 39
```

I want to call every parent array 'name'(= "arrayname0", "arrayname1" and "arrayname2).
Now I don't really know how to call this. I assumed it where keys, however whenever I try to call every key one by one it doesn't function fully:

```
foreach($arrTest as $key => $value)
{
    echo key($arrTest) . '<br />';
    next($arrTest);
}
```

This will skip the first array 'key':

```
arrayname1
arrayname2
```

Here is a fully dummy code I used:

```
$arrTest['arrayname0']['0'] = 29;
$arrTest['arrayname0']['1'] = 35;
$arrTest['arrayname0']['2'] = 39;

$arrTest['arrayname1']['0'] = 29;
$arrTest['arrayname1']['1'] = 35;
$arrTest['arrayname1']['2'] = 39;

$arrTest['arrayname2']['0'] = 29;
$arrTest['arrayname2']['1'] = 35;
$arrTest['arrayname2']['2'] = 39;

var_dump($arrTest);

foreach($arrTest as $key => $value)
{
    echo key($arrTest) . '<br />';
    next($arrTest);
}
```

I hope my question is clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do not just `echo $key;` ?

Comment: The $value i used is actually the next array with the keys 0,1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use next.

```
foreach($arrTest as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid... I thought the keys would result in the 0 , 1 and 2. Ugh, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have it wrong, use this:

```
foreach ($arrTest as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
We have a function called array_keys() shows all the keys of an array.

<?php
         $keys_arr = array_keys($arrTest);

         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($keys_arr);
?>
```

- Thanks